# Flutter and firebase app stream provider always returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

currently working on a personal project that can potentially be used by multiple churches in our area. currently on the early stage of development

im trying to print user data from firebase but the stream always returns null

here's the widget that checks if a user is logged in. i pass the UID to this widget and it checks if it's null or not

```
class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppUser? user = Provider.of<AppUser?>(context);

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      print(user.uid); // this prints successfully which means that the UID is successfully passed
      return StreamProvider<AppUserData?>.value(
        value: UserDatabaseService(user.uid).appUserData,
        initialData: null,
        child: Schedules(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

after the UID is successfully passed, it enters the Schedules page

here's the Schedules page. it's the first page to see after authentication. im trying to print the user's name here for testing

```
class Schedules extends StatelessWidget {
  Schedules({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppUserData userData = Provider.of<AppUserData>(context);

    print(userData);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(userData.name.toString())),
      body: ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _auth.signOut();
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: Text("logout"),
      ),
      drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

here, i always recieve an error

> Error: The widget Schedules tried to read Provider but the matching
> provider returned null.

which is wierd, as the UID is passed succesffully to the UserDatabaseService

```
class UserDatabaseService {
  String uid;

  UserDatabaseService(this.uid);

  // ! Collection reference to APPUSERS

  final CollectionReference appUserDataCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('AppUsers');

  Future updateAppUserdata({
    String name = 'no name',
    String churchID = 'no church',
    bool isOnChurch = false,
  }) async {
    return await appUserDataCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'name': name,
      'churchID': churchID,
      'isOnChurch': isOnChurch,
    });
  }

  // ! get user data from snapshot and maps it

  AppUserData appUserDataFromSnapshot(snapshot) {

    return AppUserData(
      name: (snapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot)['name'],
      church: (snapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot)['church'],
      isInChurch: (snapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot)['isInChurch'],
    );
  }
  // ! data stream

  Stream<AppUserData> get appUserData {
    print('successss');
    return appUserDataCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(appUserDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

I'm stuck at this problem for hours now and most google searches returns result from years ago

I am totally a beginner so any help would be appreciated and feel free to correct me if i did anything wrong.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The database documents contains `churchID` and `isOnChurch`

The while app looks for `church` and `isInChurch`